# How can I filter my data to give specific outputs

Tags: r

I have a data set on football transfer fees from across various leagues, how can I filter the data to only give me the data from the following leagues Premier League, La Liga, Ligue 1, Serie A and Bundesliga. I then need to find the mean transfer fee for each league and plot this. I have attached an image of the dataset I need to filter.

```
FT_League1<-FootballTransfers[c(2:742),c(1,7,8,10)]
```

I tried this but I still need to subset column 7 to only give me transfer fees from the leagues I want

I have attached an image of the output this gave me

[image]

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). This makes communication much easier. Posting your data as a picture is not helpful, because we can not transfer data from it to our own R session.

Answer (score 0):

```
FT_League1[FT_League1$name=="Premier League"|FT_League1$name=="La Liga"|FT_League1$name=="Ligue 1"|FT_League1$name=="Serie A"|FT_League1$name==" Bundesliga",]
```

It seems you understand how R subsets via `[row,column]` so all this is doing after the operation in your post is then filtering only the leagues with the names you specified in your question. the `|` operator stands for `OR`. So, in English this code says something akin to "from the dataframe "FT_League1", I would like to keep all rows where the variable `name` is equal to "Premier League" OR `name` is equal to "La Liga"...and so an and so forth. Then you could use `aggregate()` to get the means of each league.

If you prefer dplyr:

```
FT_League1 %>% 
filter(name==c("Premier League","La Liga","Ligue 1", "Serie A","Bundesliga") %>%
group_by(name) %>%
summarise(meanfee=mean(Transfer_fee)) %>%
ungroup()
```

Note this code is untested as you did not provide reproducible data to work with. Hope it helps.